# Spinner is not seen properly

Tags: java, android, xml, graphics, android-spinner

I have two spinner. They look like that. I don't know why dropdown menu icon is far away from texts.

[image]
(**Chagned image** after gravity attribute is set to "end")

In my activity_main.xml it is written:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map_root_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="@mipmap/map_bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/map_scroll">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_top_panel_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@mipmap/home_top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/map_spinner_sector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:gravity="end"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/map_spinner_sorting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:gravity="end"/>


</FrameLayout>

...

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

SpinnerAdapter.java class:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public SpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
    super(context,0, items);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return initView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return initView(position, convertView, parent);
}


private View initView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false
        );
    }

    TextView spinnerTextView = (TextView) convertView;
    spinnerTextView.setText(getItem(position));
    spinnerTextView.setGravity(Gravity.END); //This line is added later

    return convertView;
}
}
```

and spinner_item.xml file, which is the layout of spinner items:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am not experienced with Spinners. I am learning. I wonder why i encountered such a bug.

Not: I have **EDITED** the spinner_item.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinner_text_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="3dp"
android:paddingStart="10dp"
android:paddingEnd="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/suggestions_bg"
android:textColor="@color/blue_popular" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar problem, to solve this I had to set the attribute `gravity` in spinner.
`android:gravity="end"` - this helps to display items next to the dropdown icon.

Next, I had to override `getDropDownView` in my adapter class in this way:

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,parent);
    ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.END);
    return v;
}
```

This helps to display items next to the dropdown icon when Spinner is expanded. Your `spinner_item` is also `TextView` so I think You can just copy and paste this function.

Comment: Your solution make spinner dropdown icon closer to items. But it is still far away from items. And also it didn't affect the spinner on the right. It just affected the spinner on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Your `spinner_item.xml` file **shouldn't again contain** `Spinner`, just a `TextView` would be enough but if you want a fancy layout, you can other widgets such `ImageView`. The following is the example of the simplest `spinner_item.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_text_1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit" />
```

Now, **get rid** of implementation of `SpinnerAdapter` class.
We can use `ArrayAdapter` as adapter of `Spinner` like this :

```
// bind your spinner layout from file to a spinner object
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.map_spinner_sector);

// string array which is the content of the spinner
// if you already have array or list object, then this 
// is not needed.
ArrayList<String> spinnerStringArray = ...; // populate the array backing your adapter

// if you have string array resources in file, 
// use ArrayAdapter.createFromResource() method to get your array adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerStringArray);

spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

// set listener to handle item selected event
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("Item Selected : ", spinnerStringArray[position]);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have made changes on my codes as you said. But spinner drop down icon is still far away from items. It did not work. I edited the question, added the current layout file for spinner_item.xml

Comment: remove the `paddingEnd` attribute from `spinner_item.xml`. It adds spaces of 10 dp thats why the dropdown move farther I guess.

Comment: It have tried it, but unfortunately it didn't affect the dropdown icon. It just changes the gaps between text and the borders of the textview.

Comment: Do you still use `SpinnerAdapter` class? I suggest you to delete that class and do as I said in my answer. In the stock `Spinner`, the dropdown icon is near. Also, see if you are applying any unusual style for the `Spinner` in `styles.xml`

Comment: I tried whatever you told in the answer, so yes i deleted SpinnerAdapter class. And the style of my spinner view is the defualt one. I did not change it in anyway.

Comment: I found that it will expand as much(or a bit more) as the width of the longest `String` item that it will show in its dropdown menu. So for eg: If you have every `String` item of length 3 then it looks like what you want or in nutshell if every item's length is equal then only we can get how you want it to be I guess.

Comment: Also, if you want to make the spinner round cornered, do not put the background on `TextView` inside `spinner_item.xml` but on `Spinner` itself. The background only on `TextView` looks like `TextView` and dropdown icon are separate view.